# Getting client ID with gtag.js

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics, analytics.js, gtag.js

Google released [gtag.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/) a couple of months ago as the new way of tracking with Google Analytics, eventually replacing analytics.js as far as I understood. gtag.js is the default when setting up a new Google Analytics account, so the code snippet went from this:

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-12345678-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

to this:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-123456789-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-123456789-1');
</script>
```

What I need to do, is to get the client ID with gtag.js. With the old script, I could do as follows.

```
ga(function(tracker) {
  let clientId = tracker.get('clientId');
});
```

By the looks of it, gtag.js loads the same analytics.js script through Google Tag Manager, because the `ga` variable is indeed available. However, there is some difference because the `tracker` parameter is `undefined` when the callback is invoked, [because gtag.js does not use trackers](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/migration), so this approach clear won't work.

I looked through [the documentation for gtag.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/), but I was not able to find any information on how to obtain the client ID. The documentation for analytics.js [states not to access the cookie directly](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id#getting_the_client_id_from_the_cookie) to obtain the client ID, which makes sense. But is there any way to get it through the JavaScript API with gtag.js, or do I have to resort to reading the cookie for now?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Whlie tracker `id` property is unavailable it's still a proper ga tracker at least at the time being.
so the following would work to get a clientId:

```
ga.getAll().forEach( (tracker) => {
  var id = tracker.get('clientId'); console.log(id)
})
```

After accessing the ga tracker with ga.getAll() you can set up the 'customTask' that would assign clientId to custom dimension of your choice. Look at Simo's guide [here](https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/use-customtask-access-tracker-values-google-tag-manager/)

Comment: Ah yeah, I forgot about that approach. Unfortunately I have to rely on the `ga` variable being loaded (i.e. analytics.js), but it seems better than reading the cookie. I tested it out and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

The accepted answer does not work anymore (at least for GA4). The correct, up to date way of doing this is:

```
gtag('get', 'YOUR_MEASUREMENT_ID', 'client_id', (client_id) => {
    // do something with client_id
})
```

See the documentation for `get` in the [official Gtag.js docs](https://developers.google.com/gtagjs/reference/api#get).

Comment: you must wrap it in the promise, because client id is not returned instantly

Comment: No need for a promise. You're submitting a callback there. The accepted answer, however, still works perfectly. For Universal Analytics. The gtag approach does the trick for the GA4.

Comment: @David Chouinard Hi, do you know, how to get client id from Google Analytics 4 implemneted via Google Tag Manager? Because gtag object is not visible there.

Comment: @BNazaruk If the users are using the adblock plugin? I think it needs the promise to callback if gtag return empty.

Comment: In my case the callback is never called. Do you know what can cause it ?

Answer (score 2):

There is an undocumented way to get the clientid into GA:

```
gtag('config', 'UA-12345-1', {
  'custom_map': {
    'dimensionX': 'clientId'
  }
});
```

Obviously they wanted to provide a more convenient way to get the value (you provide literally the string 'clientId' which is then resolved into the proper value).

This was worked out by a guy named [Yamata Ryoda](https://sem-technology.info/en/google-analytics/gtag-clientid) and at length documented in an article by [Simo Ahava](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/add-clientid-to-custom-dimension-gtag-js/). I admit I haven't tested it myself yet.

Comment: I did see that article, but my problem is that I need to access the client ID in JavaScript. I am by no means a GA expert, but as I understand the code snippet, it will send the client ID to GA as a custom dimension. In other words, it doesn't let me access the value directly through JavaScript, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: You are right of course. Someday I will learn to read questions properly before I try to answer them.

Comment: Haha no worries - thanks for trying to help out! :-)

Comment: According to the docs the parameter should be named "client_id" (instead of "clientId"). See https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/migration#client_id_and_user_id