# get client id through custom js in GTM

Tags: google-tag-manager

i'm trying to get the client_id of the cookie. i need to do it with gtag so i was using this function:

```
   function(){
Promise.resolve(gtag('get', 'G-XXXXXXXX', 'client_id', function(clientID){
    var a = clientID
}))
return a
}
```

I used a promise because without it i can't get it. I already try this in console and it works.

[console pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ob7gc.png)
[undefined pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQgtV.png)

So i was doing a custom js in GTM, to get the value of that client_id, but the problem is that i get undefined in gtm, but when i put console.log() in GTM the client_id is show in the console, anybody had tried this? or knows if there is a problem with custom js and GTM?

Answer (score 0):

Never ever use any async (Promises included) in GTM vars. GTM vars only work for sync code. In the event loop, when you use Promise even for sync code, it will return the value at the very beginning of the next iteration of the loop. You can use this simple example to understand the sequencing better:

```js
(new Promise((r)=>{console.log('a');r()})).then(()=>new Promise(()=>{console.log('b')}));console.log('c')
```

b will always go after c. Same with your variable. At the time when GTM uses its value, it's still undefined.

You have a few options:

1. Take the value directly from the cookie (it's called _ga). You can use either the cookie variable or CJS variable to get it from the cookie in GTM. Better use the cookie variable, it's smaller.
2. Stop using promise. Use examples from here: [Getting client ID with gtag.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48368486/getting-client-id-with-gtag-js/48380241)
3. Run your code in a promise, but on the page load and in the promise's callback (in the then), run a datalayer push, pushing both an event indicating that the value is available and the value itself. Then make another tag that would be triggered on that DL event. This option is overengineered though, there's no need for it.